# Crossing back into Canada with alcohol already purchased in Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, borders, alcohol

I am a Canadian resident.  I recently crossed into the U.S. as part of my vacation and will be re-entering Canada after 4 days in the U.S.

When I entered the U.S, I already had alcohol in my RV (which I did declare since the border crossing guard asked when I entered the U.S)   This alcohol was purchased in Canada.  When I re-enter Canada, I will be bringing back the same alcohol that I initially purchased in Canada. I did not purchase any alcohol in the U.S. My question is: Will the alcohol that I purchased in Canada and brought into the U.S. need to be declared as part of my exemption amount being "imported" into Canada when I return to Canada?  I didn't think it would since it was already purchased in Canada.

Comment: Do you have proof that it was purchased in Canada?

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately I do not have the proof. One may be able to tell by the un-opened packaging (beer/wine), which is bi-lingual and states that the product was imported to Canada.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I agree, I'll call the CSBA and it probably would ultimately depend on who you get at the border. Thanks, I'll post what I find out!  Cheers

Comment: @user32569 any update?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the onus is on you to prove you purchased it in Canada before departure.  CBSA has [a section on their site called 'protecting your valuables'](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ifcrc-rpcrc-eng.html) that covers this:

> If your laptop computer was made in Japan—for instance—you might have
>   to pay duty and taxes on it each time you bring it back into Canada,
>   unless you can prove that you owned it before you left on your trip.
>   **Documents that fully describe the item—such as sales receipts**,
>   insurance policies, or jeweller's appraisals—are acceptable forms of
>   proof.
>
> To make things easier, **we provide a free identification service that**
>   lists items that have serial numbers or other unique markings, making
>   them identifiable for customs purposes as goods you possessed before
>   leaving Canada. All items listed will be allowed duty-free entry upon
>   your return.
>
> Please note that this service does not apply to jewellery; because
>   jewellery often has significant value, we recommend you travel with as
>   little as possible. We also recommend you carry valuable items with
>   you.

It would appear that if you've not done this, and don't have receipts, then they'll have to assume you purchased them outside of Canada.